# Not a valid json request, from DolphinDB JSON API

Tags: json, database, dolphindb

I'm trying the JSON API provided by DolphinDB, following this [tutorial](https://github.com/dolphindb/api-json).
And I tried the code snippet like this:

```
var code = "1+2";
code = encodeURIComponent(code);
paramJson = {
    "sessionID": "942605602",
    "functionName": "executeCode",
    "params": [{
        "name": "script",
        "form": "scalar",
        "type": "string",
        "value": code
    }]
}
var option = {
    url: "http://localhost:9920",
    async: true,
    data: paramJson,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var resultJson = data; 
        console.log(data);
    }
}
$.ajax(option);
```

Here is the log I got from chrome:

```
{sessionID: "800870454", userId: "", resultCode: "1", msg: "not a valid json request [sessionID=942605602&func…type%5D=string&params%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=1%252B2].", object: Array(0)}msg: "not a valid json request [sessionID=942605602&functionName=executeCode&params%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=script&params%5B0%5D%5Bform%5D=scalar&params%5B0%5D%5Btype%5D=string&params%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=1%252B2]."object: []resultCode: "1"sessionID: "800870454"userId: ""__proto__: Object
```

It report `not a valid json request`, but I don't know what's wrong with my request.

Comment: `dataType: "json"` does **not** turn your data into JSON in jQuery. Compare [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Quote: *"The type of data that you're expecting back from the server."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try serializing JSON objects before sending requests

```
data = JSON.stringify(paramJson)
```